# Whats wrong with .NetCore reflection on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Can anyone tell me why a .NetCore MVC site which works fine locally fails to start on Azure if I call this function during startup:

```
  private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string password)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.path.to.certificate.cert.pfx");

            byte[] data;

            using (resourceStream)
            {
                data = resourceStream.ReadFully();

            }

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(data, password);
            return cert;
        }
```

If I remove this call, the site starts fine, if not I get 502 error.

**Please note this function works fine on local IIS and IISExpress.**

Answer (score 0):

The name of the resource should be: `<Base namespace>.<RelativePathInProject>.<FileName>`. Also the resource have to be *Embedded Resource*

So if your resource is located in "Resources/Certs/", and your default project namespace is "MyProject.Test", the resource name is: `"MyProject.Test.Resources.Certs.Certificate.cert.pfx"`

But there can be other issue - extra dotting in the file name.
If you are trying to load resources that are compiled into your assembly as Embedded Resources, it appears you can’t use extra “dotting” in your naming convention or the compilers won’t properly add your file to the manifest, at which point all calls to GetManifestResourceStream will return null.
As I can see you have `pathtocertificate.cert.pfx`. Try to have just `certificate.pfx`.

Comment: The code works perfectly on my local machine. The resource stream is found and the certificate works once loaded. It is only on Azure this code causes an error.